# Responsive Layout Not Working Properly Using Foundation 3

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am in the process of creating a site using Foundation 3, but I cannot seem to get the responsive layout to work. The nav bar seems to be responsive when the screen size is changed, but none of the rest of the site works. Can anyone help as to how I can get the rest of the site responsive?

You can view it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52725754/fight-back-jujitsu/index.html

Any help would be appricated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on on your site. One big thing I noticed is that you are nesting `row` within `row`. That will mess up the layout of your site. If you want to have that nesting then you need to have a `columns` first and then a `row`. You can [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4w7r/) that illustrates what I'm talking about here. You will notice that the second panel causes to have a horizontal scrolling. If you remove the `row` class on that div the scrolling will go away.